# How to add a background color to table row based on data in table cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

I am using Angular `*ngFor` directive to generate my dynamic table. Here is the structure below :

```
         <tr class="tr1" *ngFor="let participant of allParticipants">

            <td class="participant-properties">{{participant.stakeholderId}}</td>

            <td class="participant-properties">{{participant.name}}</td>

            <td class="participant-properties">{{participant.rating}}</td>

         </tr>
```

[image]

Above table load when I go to that specific page. Above mentioned `tr`, last table data (`td`) has there values for `rating:active` .rejected and warn. I want to color the entire table row which has the value `active` in green, `warn` in yellow and `rejected` in red at the time of display it.

Comment: I dont know if angular template engine does support this, but in riotjs you could add the data template inside class attribute, like `<tr class="tr1 {{participant.rating}}"...` this way you cloud have `tr.active` and so on in your css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a class for each style, like so:

```
tr.active td {
  background-color: #ddffdd;
}

tr.warn td {
  background-color: #ffffbb;
}

tr.rejected td {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
  padding: 3px;
}
```

And then apply the class using `ngClass`, like so:

```
<tr class="tr1" *ngFor="let participant of allParticipants" [ngClass]="participant.rating">
```

**[Here is a Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dghzzc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you:

```
$("table tr").find('td:last').each(function(){
    let td = $(this);
    let text = td.text();
    let color = 'white';
    switch (text) {
        case 'rejected': color = 'red'; break;
        case 'warn': color = 'orange'; break;
        case 'active': color = 'green'; break;
    }

    td.css('backgroundColor', color);
});
```

Comment: Is this jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[ngStyle]` to bind to a method which would return the appropriate color.

In the template add the `[ngStyle]` to the `<tr>`:

```
<tr class="tr1" *ngFor="let participant of allParticipants" [ngStyle]="getBgColor(participant.rating)">

    <td class="participant-properties">{{participant.stakeholderId}}</td>

    <td class="participant-properties">{{participant.name}}</td>

    <td class="participant-properties">{{participant.rating}}</td>

</tr>
```

In the controller you can use a `switch case` or a `Map` to check the condition and return the appropriate style as an `Object` to the `[ngStyle]` binding in the template.

```
getBgColor(rating: string){
    switch(rating)
    {
      case'active':
       return {'background':'#b3ffcc'};
      case 'warn':
       return {'background':'#ffffb3'};
      case 'rejected':
       return {'background':'#ffb3b3'};
    }
 }
```

Here is a stackblitz demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4gb9vh